# connect() giving error in UDP client server for IPv6 address in C windows

Tags: c, windows, sockets, gcc

Here I am trying to send and receive data from server using IPV6 address in windows. In client code I am not getting the address of server so as to send data or receive data. While testing my code I found that **Connect()** in client code is giving runtime error. There might be possiblity that I cannot copying address in **memmove()** correctly. In client code actually I have tried to use **gethostbyaddr()** but still could'nt send or receive data.. Help me with this. That How can I connect to server...Also send and receive data.. Thanks in advance

***/*client side code Udp_win_IP6_Client.c*/***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>   
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")    
int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in6 client6;
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    int wsaerr;
    socklen_t size;
    struct hostent *server;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    char buffer[1024] = "Hi Harshpal Server";   
    int k;
    printf("\n Ready for Sending...\n");
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    SOCKET clientsockfd;
    clientsockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (clientsockfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
        printf("\n Error.... ");
    else
        printf("\n Successful Creation....");

    server = gethostbyname("::1");
    if(server < 0)
        printf("\n Couldnt get hostname");
    else
        printf("\n Got the hostname");

    memset((char *) &client6, 0, sizeof (client6));
    printf("\n Memory set \n");
    client6.sin6_flowinfo = 0;
    client6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;            
    memmove((char *) &client6.sin6_addr.s6_addr, (char *)server->h_name, server->h_length);
    client6.sin6_port = htons(5000);

    size = sizeof client6;
   if (connect(clientsockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client6, sizeof (client6)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("ERROR connecting");
   else
        printf("Connected...");
    printf("Type a sentence to send to server:\n");
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    printf("You typed: %s\n", buffer);

    int n = send(clientsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1, 0);
    sendto(clientsockfd, buffer, n, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client6, size);

    memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
    n = recvfrom(clientsockfd, buffer, 1024, 0, NULL, NULL);    
    printf("This is Message Received from server: %s\n", buffer);
    closesocket(clientsockfd);    
    return 0;
}
```

***/*Server side code Udp_win_IP6_Server.c */***

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
    #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    int wsaerr;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    char buffer[1024];
    int k;
    printf("\n Ready for Receiving...\n");
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);    
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

    SOCKET sockfd;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if(sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
        printf("\n Error.... ");    
    else
        printf("\n Successful Creation....");      
    struct sockaddr_in6 server6;
    memset(&server6, 0, sizeof (server6));
    server6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    server6.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    server6.sin6_port = htons(5000);

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server6 , sizeof(server6))==-1)
    {
        printf("\n Error in binding..\n");       
    }
    else{
        printf("\n Binding successful...\n");
    }
    k = sizeof(server6);

    recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server6, &k);     
    printf("\n Message from client %s: ", buffer);

    strcpy(buffer,"Hi Harshpal Client...");
    sendto(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &server6,k);
    closesocket(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

- Run code directly using gcc Udp_win_IP6_Server.c -o Udp_win_IP6_Server.o
- and gcc Udp_win_IP6_Client.c -o Udp_win_IP6_Client.o
- Or you can run in any IDE.
- No need to specify address or port while running code as I have given in  code.

Comment: the posted code seems to be missing #include statements for: `<sys/types.h>` `<sys/socket.h>`  `<string.h>`  `<arpa/inet.h>`

Comment: those calls to `gcc` will compile/link the code, they will NOT run the code

Comment: caveat: I'm not too familiar with ipv6.   regarding this line: `server = gethostbyname("::1");`  normally the parameter is something like: `"google.com"` as normally the domain name is the contents of the char string used for a parmeter

Comment: @user3629249 thanks for reply... Those header file you have mentioned..I guess that runs on linux only...I get error if I include it. I want this code to be run on windows only. And I am also confused about server = gethostbyname("::1")....I tried to use **gethostbyaddr**...but nothing changes in it.. :-(

Comment: do you know the domain  name of the server you want to connect to?  If so, then that is what I would use as the parameter to `gethostbyname()`

Comment: okay...I was actually thinking of giving "::1" as I used in `gethostbyname2` in linux...but in windows no function exist like `gethostbyname2` so I used `gethostbyname` in windows by giving "::1" or `localhost`...but it is not working because may be it is only for IPV4. And does not support IPV6...

Comment: Do you have any related code which explains `struct sockaddr_in6` for UDP in windows... I am confused about it.

Comment: you might want to read: <http://linux.die.net/man/7/ipv6> which discusses many of the items that need changes to use the ipv6 addressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer....Here is my code...Happy to share with you..... Keep Server.c same and Only replace client.c by following code :-)

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <mstcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
int main() {

    char Buffer[1024] = "This is Client \n";
    char FromServerBuffer[1024];
    char hostname[1024];

    SOCKADDR_STORAGE From;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    ADDRINFO Hints, *AddInf, *AI;
    int RetVal, gaddr, i;
    LPSOCKADDR sockaddr_ip;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    // Intializing dll required..
    memset(&Hints, 0, sizeof (Hints));

    char ipstringbuffer[50];
    DWORD ipbufferlength = 50;

    SOCKET ConnSocket;
    Hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    Hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    Hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    // Setting family, socktype and flag.
    gaddr = getaddrinfo("::1", "5000", &Hints, &AddInf);
    // getaddrinfo() will give information about address.

    for (AI = AddInf; AI != NULL; AI = AI->ai_next) {
        sockaddr_ip = (LPSOCKADDR) AI->ai_addr;
        // This loop to place IP and port into the list of IP addresses.
        int iRetval = WSAAddressToString(sockaddr_ip, (DWORD) AI->ai_addrlen, NULL, ipstringbuffer, &ipbufferlength);
        // Convert address in readable format..
        printf("\tIPv6 address %s\n", ipstringbuffer);

        ConnSocket = socket(AI->ai_family, AI->ai_socktype, AI->ai_protocol);
        // Creating Socket...
        if (ConnSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
            printf("socket call failed.. \n");

        if (connect(ConnSocket, AI->ai_addr, (int) AI->ai_addrlen) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
            // Connecting client socket to server..
            printf("Connection Establish..\n");
        } else
            printf("Connection not establish..");

        int FromLen = sizeof (From);
        RetVal = send(ConnSocket, Buffer, sizeof (Buffer), 0);
        // Sending data to server using send().
        //RetVal = sendto(ConnSocket, Buffer, sizeof (Buffer), 0, (LPSOCKADDR) & From, FromLen);
        if (RetVal < 0) {
            printf("Sending failed..\n");

        } else
            printf("Sending Successful..\n");

        int AmountRead = recvfrom(ConnSocket, FromServerBuffer, sizeof (FromServerBuffer), 0, (LPSOCKADDR) & From, &FromLen);
        // Receiving data using recvfrom..
        printf("Data Received From Server: %s", FromServerBuffer);

    }
    closesocket(ConnSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `if (server < 0)` check is incorrect, as `server` is a pointer, hence unsigned. You only need to check whether it is `NULL`. Also `gethostbyname()` is deprecated, but let it be for the sample code.

Memmove part also seems wrong. You need to take resolved address from `h_addr_list`, not from `h_name`. So your `client6` initialization should be:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 client6;
memset(&client6, 0, sizeof(client6));
client6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
client6.sin6_port = htons(5000);
memcpy(&client6.sin6_addr, server->h_addr_list[0], server->h_length);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply... I have tried as u said here but I am still getting error in the value of **server**. I checked if(server == NULL)...and it says that "Could not get the hostname", I am not getting why server not storing host data using function gethostbyname(::1);  I am getting this error "Signal received: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)"

Comment: It was not clear from your question that you get error there, I thought you get it later after `connect()` call. Sure you will get segfault when dereferencing NULL pointer in `memcpy`. I suggest you to use `getaddrinfo()` instead of `gethostbyname()` as it it deprecated and can't resolve IPv6 address strings correctly (only IPv6 hostnames are supported).

Comment: Or you may use `inet_pton` to resolve "::1" into address. But it doesn't support domain names, so I'd go with `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: Actually in Linux I have used `server = gethostbyname2("::1", AF_INET6);` and this code works perfect. This UDP_SERVER code supports both IP4 and IP6. But in windows there is no function like `gethostbyname2`....so thats made a problem..and now I am still with that problem...Also I dont know why windows is not supporting `inet_pton`. To resolve "::1" I typed "localhost" but I guess it is taking `127.0.0.1` not IP6...But fact is that I want to run this code in windows without changing `structure` which is needed for `getaddrinfo`

Comment: Windows does support `inet_pton` (both as ANSI `inet_pton` and WSA-specific `InetPton`), but not `gethostbyname2`. That's why you'd better use `getaddrinfo` which is the same on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Do you have any related code which explains `struct sockaddr_in6` for UDP in windows... I am confused about it.

Comment: @HarshpalGosavi explains it how? It is the same for UDP as for TCP (and almost the same as for IPv4), regardless of the target OS. It just holds socket address information (address family, address and port). Do you need an example of `getaddrinfo` usage or something?